# Error using sin. Not enough input arguments. Why is that so?

Tags: matlab

i am solving a mathematical problem and i can't continue do to the error.

I tried all constant with `sin^2(x)` yet its the same.

clear
clc

```
t = 1:0.5:10;
theta = linspace(0,pi,19);

x = 2*sin(theta)

y = sin^2*(theta)*(t/4)
```

Error using sin
Not enough input arguments.

Error in lab2t114 (line 9)
y = sin^2*(theta)*(t/4)

Comment: Sin must be provided theta first. Then you can square it. `sin(theta)^2`

Comment: Also, you probably want _element-wise_ squaring: `sin(theta).^2`

Answer (score 1):

`sin` is a function so it should be called as `sin(value)` which in this case is `sin(theta)` It may help to consider writing everything in intermediate steps:

```
temp = sin(theta);
y = temp.^2 ...
```

Once this is done you can always insert lines from previous calculations into the next line, inserting parentheses to ensure order of operations doesn't mess things up. Note in this case you don't really need the parentheses.

```
y = (sin(theta)).^2;
```

Finally, Matlab has matrix wise and element wise operations. The element wise operations start with a period '.' In Matlab you can look at, for example, `help .*` (element wise multiplication) and `help *` matrix wise calculation. For a scalar, like `2` in your example, this distinction doesn't matter. However for calculating y you need element-wise operations since `theta` and `t` are vectors (and in this case you are not looking to do matrix multiplication - I think ...)

```
t = 1:0.5:10;
theta = linspace(0,pi,19);

x = 2*sin(theta) %times scalar so no .* needed

sin_theta = sin(theta);
sin_theta_squared = sin_theta.^2; %element wise squaring needed since sin_theta is a vector
t_4 = t/4; %divide by scalar, this doesn't need a period
y = sin_theta_squared.*t_4; %element wise multiplication since both variables are arrays
```

OR

```
y = sin(theta).^2.*(t/4);
```

Also note these intermediate variables are largely for learning purposes. It is best not to write actual code like this since, in this case, the last line is a lot cleaner.

**EDIT:** Brief note, if you fix the `sin(theta)` error but not the .^ or .* errors, you would get some error like "Error using  * Inner matrix dimensions must agree." - this is generally an indication that you forgot to use the element-wise operators